# nginx proxy_pass weird url escaping ? (try it)

Tags: url, proxy, nginx, escaping

The original URL is:

http://www.sitmo.com/gg/latex/latex2png.2.php?z=100&eq=%5Ccos%20%7Bx%7D%2B%5Csin%20%7Bx%7D%3DCV

For some sandbox flash security reason i need to create a proxy on my domain,

```
   location /latex_gen/ {
       proxy_pass    http://www.sitmo.com/gg/latex/latex2png.2.php?z=100&eq=;
   }
```

Which now points to 
http://www.edoboard.com/latex_gen/%5Ccos%20%7Bx%7D%2B%5Csin%20%7Bx%7D%3DCV

If you look at this two urls they generate images, but in the second case the "+" are missing.
Is that because of some sort of escaping?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah the edoboard version is eating the character some how. There are a few ways it could happen.

But more importantly, rather than using somebody elses server (if you are) why don't you  host the [latex2png](http://hausheer.osola.com/latex2png) yourself?!

Comment: I tried hard installing MathTrans server with no success. I am open to any good ones which take care of security: latex poisoning etc ..Thanks

Comment: Do you think http://hausheer.osola.com/latex2png can handle the charge as well as a daemonized tex server ?